# Can a pull-up network in complementary logic circuit have both NMOS and PMOS devices?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

Consider this boolean function and its complement which will be implemented in a complementary logic circuit:

\$T = \bar{v}.\bar{w} + u.\bar{w} \$

\$\bar{T} = (v+w).(\bar{u}+w)\$

I designed the pull-up network like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPXfUG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The implementation of the pull-up network i.e. the circuit that will connect \$T\$ to \$V_{dd}\$ has 3 PMOS and 1 NMOS. It seems to make sense: there will be a connection if \$v=0\$ *and* \$w=0\$ or if \$u=1\$ *and* \$w=0\$.

My question is: should a pull-up network be exclusively PMOS based and a pull-down network be exclusively NMOS based? If so, how can it be done for \$T\$?

Comment: why not cmos??? also you have no  \$\bar{u}\$

Comment: This looks messy.

Comment: see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149615/pullup-and-pulldown-network-in-cmos

Comment: The function has no \$\bar{u}\$ - that's whats throwing me off about the pull-up network.